# Python string replacement with the same number of '*'s

Tags: python, string, replace, pycharm

I'm trying to replace a given word in the string with the same number of '*'s and then print that new string. But it's not working

```
def censor(text , word):
  l = len(word)
  k = " " + str(word) + " "
  if k in text:
     text.replace(k , l*'*')
  return text

print censor('this word duck and this word duck is censored', 'duck')
```

Comment: Please, provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This has been asked plenty of times. Gotta find a dupe vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable. That means their methods don't change the object. If anything they return a new object. This is the case with str.replace. `text.replace` returns a modified string but you don't keep it, and `text` itself is not modified. You need to do this:

`text = text.replace(k , l*'*')`

I recommend reading the official Python tutorial.